Power BI Choropleth Map Legend Sort not by distribution but by a custom order
I am building a Power BI Choropleth map using the January 2024 PBI desktop version and would like some assistance setting a custom sort order for the map.
Currently, the sort order for the legend is being shown in the order of distribution but I would like to get it by a specific physical order of data as seen in the sample table, colordistributionmaster.
The data for the issue is available here: DB fiddle
I have used County for the "Locations" field, elignumber for the "values" field and colordistribution for the legend field. The data for this comes from the table, finalchoroplethdata.
I am using default theme colors and no custom data colors are being used here.


I did try joining the tables finalchoroplethdata and colordistributionmaster, using the column, colordistribution, and attaching an index column to sort the data in colordistributionmaster, but it had no effect on the legend sort order.
I did try the option of "Sort a column by other column option" too.

I am expecting the legend to be ordered in this fashion in ascending order:
'0-99' '100-199' '200-299' '300-399' '400-500'

Wanted to add what finally worked for me:


I was able to resolve this issue. I had mistakenly used a column for slicer from an unrelated/unlinked table in the report and by using the correct slicer column, the data is being sliced correctly plus the sort order is shown in order, albeit in descending order.

You could create a column that gets everything on one side of the dash, and then convert that to a number, then sort the "Color Distribution" by that column (either ascending or descending), and that should solve your problem.

Would you mind elaborating on your comment, please? Did you mean sorting the colordistribution column in the finalchoroplethdata table or the colordistributionmastertable?

Notice how if you take the first number in the range (to the left of the dash): '0-99' '100-199' '200-299' '300-399' '400-500', and then convert it to a number, and sort it...voila! your column is sorted? maybe duplicate the column and split it on a dash and delete the other column or... and then once it's converted to a number, it sorts in numerical order.

Thank you for your suggestion. As I mentioned earlier, the solution besides sorting the legend in the master table and using it in the legend field, what prevented proper ascending order was a setting called "Show items with no data" on the legend field. Once I set that, the sorting came back to ascending, even when distribution across legends was arbitrary.
